# Run Python script at startup using upstart

Tags: centos, process, daemon, startup, upstart

I'm trying to create an upstart script to run a python script on startup. In theory it looks simple enough but I just can't seem to get it to work. I'm using a skeleton script I found [here](http://newcome.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/running-programs-as-linux-daemons-using-upstart/) and altered.

```
description "Used to start python script as a service"
author "Me <me@I.com.au>"

# Stanzas
#
# Stanzas control when and how a process is started and stopped
# See a list of stanzas here: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#respawn

# When to start the service
start on runlevel [2345]

# When to stop the service
stop on runlevel [016]

# Automatically restart process if crashed
respawn

# Essentially lets upstart know the process will detach itself to the background
expect fork

# Start the process
script
  exec python /usr/local/scripts/script.py
end script
```

The test script I want it to run is currently a simple python script that runs without any issue when run from a terminal.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import os, sys, time 
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    for i in range (10000):
        message = "UpstartTest " , i , time.asctime() , " - Username: " , os.getenv("USERNAME")
        #print message
    time.sleep(60)
        out = open("/var/log/scripts/scriptlogfile", "a")
        print >> out, message
        out.close()
```

- The location/var/log/scripts has permissions 777
- The file /usr/local/scripts/script.py has permissions 775
- The upstart script /etc/init.d/pythonupstart.conf has permissions 755

Comment: Your test script is not fork()ing so your [expect](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect) line is probably wrong.  Are you really sure you want to respawn?

Comment: This is just a test script I will want the script I plan to run in production to respawn. I'll take out the fork() and see how I go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upstart scripts go in **/etc/init** not **/etc/init.d**,
It was a long week that week. :(

Answer (score 1):

- Do not use `respawn` initially. See:

  - http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn
  - http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#precepts-for-creating-a-job-configuration-file
- Does python really fork? If not, remove `fork`.
- You can simplify the stanza to start your job to simply:

  exec python /usr/local/scripts/script.py
- What does `/var/log/upstart/yourjob.log` show?

Comment: /var/log/upstart isn't there but upstart is installed.   /sbin/initctl --version returns "initctl (upstart 0.6.5) Copyright (C) 2010 Canonical Ltd." Does Upstart need to be configured to start at startup or is it automatic, I didn't install it. It was there when I installed the OS.

Comment: sudo /etc/init.d/script.conf gives the following output
`line 3: description: command not found
line 4: author: command not found
start: Unknown job: on
stop: Unknown job: on
line 18: respawn: command not found
Script started, file is typescript`

Comment: Upstart scripts go in /etc/init not /etc/init.d :(